# iPhone with Exchange Email

Tags: email, sync, itunes, iphone, exchange

Quick question really - how can I sync my iPhone with my Exchange account - syncing calenders, contacts and emails, while also keeping all the existing contacts on my iPhone?

The reason I ask is because Exchange will overwrite any existing contacts on the phone when it syncs with the iPhone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my ancient iOS 4: Settings -> Mails, Contacts, Calendars -> Add Account -> Exchange

Comment: Although this is how you do it - when Exchange syncs contacts from Outlook, it overwrites any contacts on the iPhone, which is what Im asking advice about.

Comment: It didn't do it on my iPhone. I use Exchange to access my google account, and it left my contacts in tact. After importing my phone contacts in google, i still had the duplicates, labelled as "linked contacts". From time to time, I delete the iphone-entry in favor of the google entry.