# iPhone Contact Sync

Tags: email, iphone, exchange, activesync

I have a new iPhone, which is synced with iTunes for music. I have around 200 contacts on here - I read somewhere if I sync now my iPhone with Exchange, it will overwrite all my contacts, leaving my with only my contacts from my Exchange account? Is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems better suited for [apple.se]. Furthermore, it's pretty much the same as [your previous question on the same subject](http://superuser.com/questions/486958/iphone-with-exchange-email).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the exchange contacts will be in another contacts group.

For example, I have my personal contacts in icloud group that is what I guess your 200 contacts are also in, and company contacts in exchange group the name depends on your "mail, contacts, calendar" setting of settings.

I could see both of them together from "All contacts" group.

Answer (score 1):

When you sync your iPhone to an activesync exchange account, you have the option of syncing e-mail, contacts, and calendar. Simply select that you only want to sync your e-mail. However if you do sync contacts I don't believe contacts will be overwritten, it may just create duplicate contacts though.